# Conversion from java to kotlin confuses me

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

In Intellij Idea I use the function 'Convert Code From Java'

```
public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket) {
   WebSocket.Listener.super.onOpen(webSocket);
}
```

to Kotlin

```
override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket) {
   super@Listener.onOpen(webSocket)
}
```

But ...@Listener... is red marked as error without working suggestion. What could be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write `super<WebSocket.Listener>.onOpen(webSocket)`. Check out [overriding rules](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#overriding-rules).